# Error local deployment Websphere

Tags: java, sdk, websphere, cdi, jdk1.7

I've been struggling with this error whenever I start my local server.
What I have done:
1. removing and adding project which didn't help at all
2. updating my `JAVA_HOME`

FYI, I'm working with **jdk 1.7** and **Websphere 8.5.5.8**

Error below is the one causing the deployment goes boink

> [ERROR] CWWKZ0002E: An exception occurred while starting the
>   application APP_war_exploded. The exception message was:
>   com.ibm.ws.container.service.state.StateChangeException:
>   org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: incompatible
>   InnerClasses attribute between
>   "com.ibm.ws.beanvalidation.v11.cdi.internal.ValidationExtension$AnnotatedTypeFilter"
>   and "com.ibm.ws.beanvalidation.v11.cdi.internal.ValidationExtension"

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Andy's answer here](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/200771/liberty-8556-jee7-fails-to-deploy-ear-file-incompa.html), it looks like you need to update your SDK to the latest version of 1.7, like 7.1.3 or greater.

Comment: I used oracle instead and create new server profile. Thanks for the help anyway!